# prevent images being loaded until click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slice

I currently have a list of images and text, we have about 1000 images so the page load is slow.

I have a hide and show function that only loads the next three when clicked using js slice method.

My images are loaded from wp php loop, I cant use Ajax due to server limitations, is there a simple way to not load the images until the user clicks the button ?

**Question**

My question is how do I prevent all images from being loaded until the users clicks the button to show the next 3 images
I have tried

```
$(".secondary-card").each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        obj.data("objsrc", obj.attr("data-src"));
        obj.hide().attr("data-src", "").before("<span class=\"loading\">loading . . .</span>");
    });
```

but my page dose not seem much faster

Here is my current code to load the next 3 images

```
const cards = $('.card-deck')
let clicks = 3;

if (cards.length > 3) {
    cards.hide();
    cards.slice(0, 3).show();
}
$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
    clicks = clicks + 3;
    if (clicks > cards.length) {
        clicks = cards.length
    }
    cards.slice(0, clicks).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using native [loading=lazy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/loading)? think it's better for SEO and js blocker

Comment: currently using https://apoorv.pro/lozad.js/

Comment: Try to use your logic inside a function called with any name and trigger it on click event only.

Comment: Can you show how your php code creates the cards ?

Comment: just the basic wordpress loop <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post(); 
  //
  // Post Content here
  //
 } // end while
} // end if
?>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach you can proceed with:

```
$(.cards-desk).hide();
$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
  $(.cards-desk).append("You images html code");
  $(".cards-desk").show()
});
```

Comment: problem here my image html is a php loop

Comment: Then use pagination in two ways > backend or frontend

Comment: not using pagination, want all on one page and show more or less without ajax